# migrating mysql DBs from one host to another, encoding issues

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I am migrating a very large number of mysql DBs from a few shared web hosts to one shared web host.

The majority of these are Portuguese, so there's quite a few special characters. Some of the DBs which I am migrating are in latin1, some are cp1251, some are utf8.

Of course, simply dumping the DBs, and then restoring the dumps onto the new host completely botches the encoding and "?" characters and other nonsense shows up in the actual websites associated with the databases.

On a small scale, it would be acceptable to muck about with the html charset tags, to know what to dump/restore as, but the problem is that we're dealing with thousands databases and websites, and the migrations are all done automatically via several scripts.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way of dumping/restoring these DBs assuming that the script doing the work **will not know the encoding which is specified in the HTML tags**.

So far, I have tried using the actual mysqldump tool, as well as mimicking it with a php script, and dumping to and from memory instead of to and from a text file, neither of these seem to replicate the data perfectly from one to the other without encoding issues.

Should I be using UTF8 to encode the dump, then restoring as is regardless of the html codepage?
Dumping and restoring both in UTF8 regardless of HTML codepage?
Dumping and restoring in the default charset found in each create table statement?

My understanding of the implications and effects of these different scenarios is limited, but what I need to know is basically **if there is a way to perfectly replicate data without encoding issues between 2 database servers without knowing the codepage used by the HTML of the script which is accessing the data.**

Comment: Did you try copying all the data files in mysql dir (.MYD and .MYI) to the new server?

Comment: I do not have access to do so, we have only the same access that the customer who owns the databases would have, that is, connection to the DB. No admin or root access.

Answer (score 0):

Encodings are a very difficult problem to tackle, especially when moving databases. Try first to do a structural import, and then compare exactly the new structure with the old one, taking special care in database character set, table default character set and columns character sets. You can get these informations very easily from the information_schema database.

Once those are absolutelly mirorred, you can begin the import. However, beware of the fact that you can hold characters in differend encoding types in differend encoded columns (it is quite common to have utf8 valid characters in a latin1 column, latin 1 is a 1 byte character set, while utf8 can have characters of up to 3 bytes).

You can try various methods after this to convert the dumps but as far as i know so far there is not a 100% valid method to convert this type of cases of mixed encoding types in same column. Eventually you might need to do some manual cleanup. But hopefully the first approach will suffice, and everything will be fine.